# Can i view a file in google drive in browser using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-drive-api

Can i view a file in google drive in browser using C#, i have tried somethings with google api. but always it's asking for login details.
How can i view file in browser using c#?

here i have tried,

```
public ActionResult GetDriveFile()
    {
        string filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/client_secret.json");
        //string filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MyProject-e09c7c94100a.json");
        string userName = "xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com";

        //GoogleCredential credential;
        //string[] Scopes = { Google.Apis.Drive.v2.DriveService.Scope.Drive };

        //using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
        //{
        //    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(Scopes);
        //}

        //var driveService = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        //{
        //    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        //    ApplicationName = "Test",
        //});


        var driveService = AuthenticateOauth(filePath, userName);

        List<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> allFiles = retrieveAllFiles(driveService);

        string fileID = allFiles.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("sample.jpg")).Select(y => y.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        //DownloadFile(driveService);

        string fileLink = GetFileLink(fileID);

        return Redirect(fileLink);
    }



public static Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService AuthenticateOauth(string clientSecretPath, string userName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                throw new Exception("userName is required.");
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(clientSecretPath))
                throw new Exception("clientSecretJson file does not exist.");

            // These are the scopes of permissions you need. It is best to request only what you need and not all of them
            string[] scopes = new string[] { Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService.Scope.Drive };                   // View and manage the files in your Google Drive         
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(clientSecretPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/apiName");

                // Requesting Authentication or loading previously stored authentication for userName
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                                                                         scopes,
                                                                         userName,
                                                                         CancellationToken.None,
                                                                         new Google.Apis.Util.Store.FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            }

            // Create Drive API service.
            return new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Drive Authentication Sample",
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Create Oauth2 DriveService failed" + ex.Message);
            throw new Exception("CreateOauth2DriveFailed", ex);
        }
    }
```

Please, anyone have any idea regarding this?

Comment: *You* have access to the file, but the rest of the world doesn't. If you redirect a user to the file on Google Drive, they will need explicit permission to access it. That means you must either make it public or otherwise grant access to each user that needs access individually. The only other option is to download it and return it as a response directly from your server. This allows you to authorize just for your application, but you'll take on additional up and down bandwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you share a file with a user using [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create) there is an option to send them a notification.  This tells them that the file is shared with them.

Now that the file is shared with them File.get returns a file [resource](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ukklnaNpOoVGnxK4PT99jFAT0BRtW7QRstXtZcnE58I/edit?usp=drivesdk) note make sure you add fields= * or you wont get much of the meta data back from file.get.

> webViewLink
>    A link for opening the file in a relevant Google editor or viewer in a browser.

Basically if the user in question has access then you will get this link back to the file.  Something like this

> https://docs.google.com/document/d/xWau_bNrntLBDDFjwUPBDkL3_oBW3hthavaVF8Ed1mbA

What I haven't been able to figure out is how to create a sharable link you can on the website so I assume there is a way of doing it though the API as well.  Currently I think the file has to either be public or the user must have access before you get a webview link back.

Comment: Whatever the link(as you mentioned above) ,we have to login to our google account to view the particular file in browser (if i have access permission) is it.? and one more thing i am getting always *null* value for *WebViewLink* and *WebContentLink* , any other configuration that i need to do in my account or in my code to get *WebViewLink* properly..?

Comment: if its yours then you should have access to the file yes.  Assuming that you are getting the field I cant tell you why it would be null.  unless maybe its not a google drive type file.  What type of file is it you are trying to access?

Comment: Hi, Actually my intention is , whoever using my application should able to access and view (in browser) these files(any file format) in my drive without logging in to their google account.is it possible using **Drive api** in c#.?

Comment: No google drive can not display any file format only specific file formats.  Assuming the file was the correct format if its public then anyone would be able to view it.   https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2423485?hl=en

Comment: The link to the doc no longer works.   I was getting emails requesting access to it :o)